# Yodlee Fastlink Token Rejected

Tags: oauth, yodlee

When making a call to get the Yodlee Fastlink form I keep getting redirected to a URL with parameters oauth_error_problem=token_rejected and oauth_error_code=413. I am generating the user token via the recommended OAuthAccessTokenManagementService.getOAuthAccessToken call immediately before creating the oauth signature and substituting them into their respective positions of the sample url as outlined here [Fastlink Integration Guide](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide#Steps_for_Invoking_Yodlee_FastLink). I am using a token generated for an account in the Private Zone, is there a separate base url that I should be using for fastlink, like there is for other REST calls? Also, is there a list of oauth-related error codes and explanations? The error codes section under FAQ does not include references to this code in particular or anything else related to oauth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error as you are using the wrong URL to connect to FastLink for the specified token.

> is there a separate base url that I should be using for fastlink, like there is for other REST calls?

Yes, the base URL for your private zone will be different than the one on the developer portal. Please contact your account manager to get the correct FastLink URL.

> is there a list of oauth-related error codes and explanations?

Right now there is no documentation on the ouath error codes. We will take this as feedback and will have documentation around it.

Comment: Looks like Yodlee created the list.  A little more explanation detail on 413 and a couple of others would probably be even more helpful, but this is a good start: https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes/OAuth_Error_Codes